# If in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
:WriteAgain
set x= 
set /p variables=Write your expression 
if "%variables%"=="help" (
echo Use arithmetical operations and numbers without spaces. + for sum, * for multiplication, / for 

devision, - for subtraction 
exit
) else (
set variables=%variables: =%
set /a x=%Variables% 2>Error.txt
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto ErrorOccured
echo %x% 
pause
exit
)
:ErrorOccured
echo Your expression is not valid 
goto WriteAgain
) else (
set variables=%*
set variables=%variables: =%
set /a x=%variables% 2>Error.txt
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto ErrorOccured
echo %x%
)
```

Greetings, It is a simple calc. It could be used right from cmd but first `if` doesn't work also it can't pass

```
) else (
set variables=%variables: =%
set /a x=%Variables% 2>Error.txt
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto ErrorOccured
echo %x%
```

always `ErrorOccured`. I don't see any problems and it worked without first `if`

Comment: `if - else - else` is not supported in batch. Also it's a bad idea to jump inside or into a `(`block`)`. Every `goto` breakes the block context. Rethink your logic (program flow).

Comment: In addition, label is not supported inside (). Also the first echo are malformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it fits your expectations and I was not able to run the `ErrorOccured` label.

```vb
@echo off
cls
set x= 

:WriteAgain
if "%1"=="" (
    set /p "variables=Write your expression " || cls &goto help
    ) else (
    set "variables=%*"
)

set variables=%variables: =%
set /a x=%variables% 2>Error.txt
:: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto ErrorOccured
if not ERRORLEVEL 0 goto ErrorOccured
call :result %variables% %x%
exit /b 0

:help
echo(
echo Use arithmetical operations and numbers without spaces.
echo + for sum, * for multiplication, / for devision, - for subtraction
goto WriteAgain

:result
echo formula is %~1 and the result is %~2
goto:EOF

:ErrorOccured
cls
echo(
echo Your expression is not valid 
goto :help

exit /b 0
```

This must certainly be optimized.

Comment: `if NOT errorlevel 0` is the same as `if %errorlevel% LSS 0` because `if errorlevel 0` statement should be read as _if errorlevel  is_ **greater than or equal** _zero_.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps next code could help. Note [`EnableDelayedExpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and proper quoting to allow all arithmetic operations seen in `set /?`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"=="" goto NeedHelp
set "variables=%*"

:CommonCalc
if "%variables%"=="" goto ErrorOccured
rem spaces do not matter set "variables=!variables: =!"
set /a "x=!variables!" 2>Error.txt
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto ErrorOccured
echo !variables!=%x%
exit /B

:WriteAgain
set "x="
set "variables="
set /p "variables=Write your expression: "
if /I "!variables!"=="" goto NeedHelp 
goto CommonCalc

:NeedHelp
echo Use arithmetical operations and numbers without spaces. 
echo + for sum, * for multiplication, / for division, - for subtraction
echo %% for modulus ^(remainder after division^)
goto WriteAgain

:ErrorOccured
echo Your "!variables!" expression is not valid ^(%errorlevel%^)
rem next line: clear errorlevel to 0
(call )
goto NeedHelp
```

However, [proper escaping](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) some operators is needful *if used as batch line parameters*. For instance:

- negation `32766441.bat ^^^!0` returns `!0=1`,
- logical *or* `32766441.bat 6^|9` returns `6|9=15`,
- left [shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) `32766441.bat 5^<^<3` returns `5<<3=40` etc.

The `(call )` trick to clear `errorlevel` by virtue of  [this dbenham's answer](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602)

Comment: If I was the OP I would have chosen your answer. +1